# General LocalDate JPA criteria building for unknown entity type

Tags: java, jpa, generics

I'm attempting to build a super generalized JPA query builder that takes some general filter and generically builds criteria for a JPA query. In other words, I want it to be used for date filtering on any sort of entity.

For example, I want a method that takes some generic entity information and creates a predicate for a `LocalDate`. To describe this, it's probably best to show what I have so far:

```
public class DatePredicateBuilder
{
    private final String dateAttribute;

    public DatePredicateBuilder(String attributeName)
    {
        this.dateAttribute = attributeName;
    }

    @Override
    public <ENTITY> Predicate getEndPredicate(
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
        final Root<ENTITY> data,
        final EntityType<ENTITY> entityType,
        final LocalDate endDate)
    {
        return criteriaBuilder.ge( 
            data.get(entityType.getSingularAttribute(dateAttribute)),
            criteriaBuilder.literal(endDate)));
    }
}
```

You can see what the goal is here, I think. I want to be able to build some `DatePredicateBuilder` class for any attribute on an entity, and have a method that builds the corresponding `Predicate` for me.

This won't compile, I think, because the generic type of the first argument (unknown) doesn't match that of the second (`LocalDate`). I can make a tweak that corrects the `CriteriaBuilder.ge` method call: `data.<LocalDate>get(...)`, but now the `getSingularAttribute` call fails, I think, because it doesn't know the attribute is `LocalDate`. This is, again, because it's so generalized that we only know the attribute name.

I don't mind casting where I need to since I'm enforcing the attribute should be a `LocalDate` (and should fail if it isn't), but I'm not sure what to cast to fix this. In other words, this is only meant to work for `LocalDate` so we can make that assumption accordingly.

I'll continue hacking it to see if I can get it to at least compile, but any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `CriteriaBuilder<?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

[entityType.getSingularAttribute(attributeName, LocalDate.class)](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/metamodel/ManagedType/getSingularAttribute_String_Class_),

then it should both compile properly, and notify the entity type itself what you expect the attribute to be, so your type requirement is also validated by JPA framework.

Your full code then:

```
@Override
public <ENTITY> Predicate getEndPredicate(
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
    final Root<ENTITY> data,
    final EntityType<ENTITY> entityType,
    final LocalDate endDate)
{
    return criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo( 
        data.get(entityType.getSingularAttribute(dateAttribute, LocalDate.class)),
        criteriaBuilder.literal(endDate)));
}
```

*Edit*:
Based on comment by OP below, also the criteria builder method to use is not `ge` (as it is intended for numeric fields), but the `greaterThanOrEqualTo`.

Comment: That helps. Somehow I didn't notice that in the javadoc. It turns out the `ge` call is still wrong though; using `greaterThanOrEqualTo` instead fixed it, as `ge` seems to be exclusively for numbers.

Comment: @Depressio, I'll update the code in my answer and your question with that method change, if you don't mind. It will improve things for people who come here from search.